Subject of the ablative absolute in the main clause
In the Historia Regum Britanniae there is the following sentence:
Superveniente ergo illa cesserunt ei Saxones et aliquantulum dilapsi vix iterum sese consociaverunt.
The editor makes the following somewhat cryptic note about the word ei: "In CL, the subj. of the abl. abs. usu. does not reappear in the main cl.". What is he talking about and what is the grammatical function of the word ei in this sentence?

In Classical Latin, the subject of the ablative absolute usually does not reappear in the main clause.
The subject of the the AA is illa and the dative ei refers to the same person.
I don't have more context than what you give, so I can't rule out there being something else the dative could refer to.
The verb cedere can go with a dative, and that's what this one seems to do.
